# Ruby class: handle any not implemented method with yaml

Tags: ruby, yaml, notimplementedexception

I want to create a special settings class `Settings`. The class should be able to handle cases when a user types something like `Settings.new.method_1.method_2.method_3` and it's translated to something like:

```
result = nil
if ConfigurationSettings['method_1'].present? 
  result = ConfigurationSettings['method_1'] 
  if result['method_2'].present?
  result = result['method_2']
  ...
end

return result
```

Of course, I'll make it more flexible later so it can have more than 2/3 "methods".

Comment: I think a hashie/mash will help you here. e.g. ```ConfigurationSettings = { 'method_1' => { 'method_2' => 'asdf' } };``` ```Hashie::Mash.new(ConfigurationSettings).method_1.method_2```

Comment: I can’t see what you’re asking here, but in particular why do you mention Yaml in the title and tags? Nothing in the question seems to have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the issue you are facing:

```
class Settings
 def abc
   puts "abc"
 end
 def xyz
   puts "xyz"
 end
end

s = Settings.new
s.abc
#abc
# => nil
s.xyz
#xyz
# => nil
s.abc.xyz
#abc
#NoMethodError: undefined method `xyz' for nil:NilClass
```

The issue here is `s.abc` is returning `nil` and `xyz` is called over `nil`. What you are trying to achieve is called [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Now, `xyz` needs an `Settings` object. Simplest thing to do here is:

```
class Settings2
  def abc
    puts "abc"
    self
  end
  def xyz
    puts "xyz"
    self
  end
end

s2 = Settings2.new
s2.abc.xyz
#abc
#xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

`method_missing` is available for your use and can be used to help you solve this problem.  Coupling this with method chaining and you're good to go.  For example:

```
class Settings
    def method_missing(meth)
        puts "Missing #{meth}"
        self
    end

    def test
        puts "Test"
        self
    end
end

a = Settings.new
a.test
a.test.b
a.b.test
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with the other answers is all the methods return "self" so if you want to access a nested value...

```
final_value = Settings.new.method_1.method_2.method_3
```

You're just going to get the whole settings hash instead.

Try this instead...

```
class Settings
  class SubSettings
    def initialize(sub_setting)
      @sub_setting = sub_setting
    end
    def method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
      if @sub_setting[method].is_a?(Hash)
        SubSettings.new @sub_setting[method]
      else
        @sub_setting[method]
      end
    end
    def answer
      @sub_setting
    end
  end
  def initialize
    @settings = ConfigurationSettings
  end
  def method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
    SubSettings.new @settings[method]
  end
end

ConfigurationSettings = {level1a: {level2a: {level3a: "hello", level3b: "goodbye"}, level2b: {level3b: "howdy"}}}

result = Settings.new.level1a.level2a.level3b
p result
=> "goodbye"
```

What this does is take the initial method and takes the associated sub-hash of the ConfigurationSettings hash and stored it into a new object of class SubSettings.  It applies the next method and if the result is another sub-hash it iterates to create another SubSettings, etc.  It only returns the actual result when it no longer sees hashes.